# Locking the Static object inside the static property in the HTTPModule

Tags: c#, programming-languages, locking

We have a custom DLL implemented `IHttpModule` to handle the `httpApplication_EndRequest`, what I want to know is

The DLL has a class (not a static class) which has a static property is used to create an instance for a static variables/object reference defined inside the class.

Now, should I need to lock inside static property before creating an instance for the static object/variable?

Eg:-

```
public class SPEnvironment : IEnvironment
{
    private static SPEnvironment _instance;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    private SPEnvironment()
    {
        try {
        .....
        }
        finally {
        ......
        }
    }

    public static SPEnvironment Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new SPEnvironment();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I will calling this from an another class, like below

```
SPEnvironment.Instance;
```

Is it the right way? or the lock should be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double null check with a lock in the middle is a good, thread-safe way of instantiating a singleton. However, you could save yourself a lot of code by just saying

```
public class SPEnvironment : IEnvironment
{
    public static SPEnvironment Instance = new SPEnvironment();

    private SPEnvironment()
    {
        try {
        .....
        }
        finally {
        ......
        }
    }
}
```

The difference between the two is that this code instantiates the singleton the first time an object of that type is created where your code instantiates the singleton the first time `SPEnvironment.Instance` is accessed. In almost all cases, those are the same thing; in most of the remaining cases, it doesn't matter; but it is a subtle distinction that is worth understanding for that very rare edge case.

Comment: this class has a private constructor

Comment: The DLL is used for the web-application, should i still need to lock the signleton object?

Comment: @CrazyNick - To answer your first question, I have corrected my code; sorry. For the second, yes. If you don't lock the object and check for null again then it is possible for two threads to check that `_instance` is null, find that it is and then instantiate the object. This *might* not matter to you as the first will be discarded, but it does mean that it won't be a true singleton.

Comment: as this is a static reference, is it possible to have a duplicate object for the same object reference?

Comment: No, but it is possible for two threads to call the Instance property simultaneously and create unexpected results. Read this discussion for more detailed info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: The `lock` is the only real performance issue here, which is why we check for `null` *before* locking the object, as well as after, so that it only gets called during instantiation rather than each read. That said, I didn't notice before but you also need to declare `_instance` as `volatile` (so that threads read the very most recent value) which can be a slight performance issue and thus another advantage of instantiating in the declaration (my version of the code).